# AJAX Form, passing return message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have my AJAX form it works great. 
Every time I submit the form It returns the result inside the `<div id="message"></div>`, but it gets complicated when I have multiple forms. So I was wondering if their is a way to indicate inside the form what `<div>` to return the message to.

Here is my AJAX.js

```
$("form#ajaxForm").on("submit", function() {
    var form = $(this),
        url = form.attr("action"),
        type = form.attr("method");
        data = {};


    form.find("[name]").each(function(index, value){
          var input = $(this),
                name = input.attr("name"),
                value = input.val();

          data[name] = value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,

        success: function(response) {
            $("#message").html(response); //I would like to interactively switch the return div, from #message to like #message2
            $("body, html").animate({ 
               scrollTop: $( $("#message") ).offset().top - 5000
            }, 600);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

In the form I would like to indicate where the return div is, like

```
    <form action="../forms/add_event_form.php" method="post" id="ajaxForm">
  //Can I add an input somewhere here? To indicate where I want the return to go too? Like <input type="hidden" value="message2" name="return">
    <input type="text" class="formI" name="date" id="dateI" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
    </form>
```

Thank you for reading this. Have a good day! And Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not work automatically, but you can add some information to the form and then use it to decide where to put returned HTML. Doing that with additional inputs may not be the best way though, as it can be achieved with far less impact on the DOM: with an attribute on the form itself.

Here's an example of how you may do that.

```js
$(".ajaxForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this);
  // using jQuery's `data()` to get an ID of response element from the 'data-response' attribute
  var responseElementId = form.data("response");
  var response = $(responseElementId); 
  response.html(produceResponse(form));


  // function that produces some html response
  // you'll use AJAX request to the server for that
  // so don't mind its complexity or bugs
  function produceResponse(form) {
    var data = form.find("input").map(function(i, el) {
      return "'" + el.name + "': " + el.value;
    });
    return "<p>You've submitted:\n<pre>" + Array.prototype.join.call(data, ",\n") + "</pre></p>";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Form #1</h2>
<form action="#" class="ajaxForm" data-response="#response1">
  <input name="first-name" type="text">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="response1"></div>

<h2>Form #2</h2>
<form action="#" class="ajaxForm" data-response="#response2">
  <input name="last-name" type="text">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="response2"></div>
```

Here I use a `data` attribute because it was [designed for cases like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes): to store arbitrary data related to the element, but which doesn't have any defined meaning for the browser. Accessing data stored in such way is really convenient with its [HTML5 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), but because of pretty low support from IE (it has it only starting from the version 11), one may use jQuery's [method `data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to do the same.